# "Translate" an Arduino Library in a Python one

Tags: python, translate

I'm new in Python programming and I need to *translate* an Arduino/C library in a Python library to use a load cell (through I2C bb **NAU7802**) with a Rapsberry Pi 3.
Since nobody has done it yet, I was asking if there was a simple way to do it. If not, can anyone suggest me a book from which to study how to make a python library for microelectronics or, even better, articles or something else for the translation of a library from one language to another?

[ The Arduino NAU7802's library is: https://github.com/Sawaiz/nau7802 ]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you **need** to run it directly on a Raspberry Pi, or can you write Python code that can interact with the Arduino via a serial connection?

Comment: I need to run directly on a Raspberry Pi, so I need to translate it. Otherwise I would have opted for a reading of the data from arduino and then a transfer of the same from arduino to raspberry (thanks for the interest!)

Comment: That source code seems extremely straightforward to me – it comes down to reading and writing bits at the lowest level, and building a set of higher-level functions from these. If you are so new to Python programming, best not begin with a full project. Start with [the official Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and when you're done, you should have an idea on how to get started with this project.